# How to turn off tool-tips on scroll-bar in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

When scrolling editor vertically in PHPStorm the inspection tool-tips popping up. The "Line xxx changed" is extremely annoying especially if many changes are made in the file. Sometimes it event prevent to click on scroll-bar. I don't see an option to turn it off in "inspections" menu. Is there any other way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 11):

In the lower right-corner, there is some sort of inspector icon. Click it to see the following:
[image]

Moving down from inspections seems to remove the yellow while moving to none removes the red.

Comment: In addition removing `error stripe mark` that was enabled for many many other things in `Editor > Colors & Fonts > General` also helped clean up the scrollbar area.

Comment: Turning it off for `Warning`, `Weak Warning`, `Todo` ... is an excellent way to get your scrollbar back.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really annoying problem, trying to use the scroll bar when there are loads of error markers (queue bad coding jibes) causing pop-ups that block it.

I have resorted to turning off the 'Error stripe marks' which lie under the scroll bar, using the check box in:

Settings > Editor > Colours & Fonts > General

I'm not sure who came up with this UI feature but they obviously didn't think it through properly.

Comment: It does not solve the problem but it's helpful - thanks

Comment: In addition it helped a lot to turn off `Inspections > Spelling > Typo > Process Comments`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable popups but you can only disable specific inspections.

- Alt+enter on line which cause inspection warning.
- When popup menu appears, press right arrow button.
- You will see Disable inspection
  sub menu.

[image]

Comment: I am interesting in disable 'line changed' in partucular

Comment: @Amorphous What "line changed"? Can you **at least** show a screenshow of such message? Which tool produces such message -- PhpStorm itself ..or maybe some 3rd party tool (e.g. CodeSniffer)?

Comment: @Amorphous Do you use any Subversion control system?

Comment: line-changed is the most annoying of them all.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. Seems like there is no way to separate the scroll from tooltips. But I found [this CodeGlance](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7275) plugin, this plugin adds a second scroll (without annoying colors) to PhpStorm's interface.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy9iY.png)